# The ListView is not generated in the Fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

I'm calling the fragment from the main activity:

```
<fragment
        android:name="com.example.project.AdExample"
        android:id="@+id/button_fragment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/ad_example"/>
```

**AdExample.java** source code:

```
public class AdExample extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // getting access to layout
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ad_example, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), initData());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    private List<MovieItem> initData () {
        List<MovieItem> list = new ArrayList<MovieItem>();

        list.add(new MovieItem("Item1", "Desc1", 2014));
        list.add(new MovieItem("Item2", "Desc2", 2014));
        list.add(new MovieItem("Item3", "Desc3", 2014));

        return list;
    }
}
```

But as a result I get a blank ListView. Have I missed something in the above code?

Thanks.

---

**UPD:**

Here is **MovieAdapter.java** source code:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<MovieItem> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<MovieItem> list) {
        this.list = list;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        name.setText(getMovieItem(position).getName());

        return view;
    }

    private MovieItem getMovieItem(int position ) {
        return (MovieItem) getItem(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code from MovieAdapter

Comment: @EarlOfEgo , the post is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your get count returns 0.
do:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```